# ES6 class methods not a function

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

I'm messing around with Javascript "classes" and I have a paddle that has a proper method to draw, but for some reason my moveBall function is messed up.  Could anyone point out why?  I get an error saying that moveBall() is not a function.

Edit:  I included some more code, I call init() to start it all.

```
class Ball {
    constructor(x, y, r, sAngle, rAngle) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.r = r;
        this.sAngle = sAngle;
        this.rAngle = rAngle;
        this.speed = null;
    }

    drawBall() {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, this.sAngle, this.rAngle);
        ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
        ctx.fill();
    }
    moveBall() {
        this.x += this.speed;

    }

}


function init() {
    var  ball = new Ball(c.height / 2, c.width / 2, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    var paddleLeft = new Paddle(0, 0, 20, 100);
    ball.ballPhysics = 1.0;
    draw(ball, paddleLeft);
    main(ball);
}


window.main = function (ball) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(main);
    ball.moveBall();
    window.onload = function () {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode === 65) {

        }
    }, false);
}

};
```

Comment: this works fine, how are you calling moveBall?

Comment: what`.moveBall`? show more code

Comment: Please read [mcve]. It's definitely helpful to at least include the line that throws the error. I assume you are doing `Ball.moveBall()`. That's simply wrong, you need to create an instance of `Ball` first.

Comment: I created an instance of ball, I edited my original post to include more code.

Comment: `requestAnimationFrame(main);` will lead to your `main` function being called without  a `ball` argument.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using it like Ball.moveBall() than it's incorrect, you must instantiate Ball class first or use static methods like

```
class A {
 static f() {
 }
}
```

and call like

`A.f();`

otherwise check the snippet below

```js
class Ball {
  constructor(x, y, r, sAngle, rAngle) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.r = r;
    this.sAngle = sAngle;
    this.rAngle = rAngle;
    this.speed = null;
  }

  drawBall() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, this.sAngle, this.rAngle);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
    ctx.fill();
  }
  moveBall() {
    this.x += this.speed;

  }
}

var greenBall = new Ball(0, 0 , 10, 0, 0);

greenBall.speed = 5;

greenBall.moveBall();

document.write(greenBall.x);
```

Answer (score 1):

make sure you have an instance of ball in the scope of the code you are trying to run, and try `var moveball = function(){this.x += this.speed; };` to see if it's a compile issue, and make sure you are accessing it like `ball.moveball()`

Answer (score 1):

You define `main` to accept an argument `ball`. But you are never calling `main`, so you cannot pass an argument to it.

While `window.requestAnimationFrame(main);` will call the function, it won't pass anything to it.

It seems you want to refer to the `ball` variable that is defined inside `init`. In that case, *remove* the parameter `ball` from the function definition so that it doesn't shadow that variable:

```
window.main = function() { ... };
```

---

You also don't want to assign to `window.onload` inside `main`, because that wouldn't happen over and over again.